# Move rigidbody continuously in a specific direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Im attempting to make a / mess around with Pirate game and I cant get the movement controls to work correctly. My intended behaviour for now is that when I press 'W' (release sails) this will move the ship continuously towards the direction that the bow is pointing. However the issue im having is that the ship actually slides around as if its on an ice rink.

[image: Ice Rink Ship]

Green arrow is the direction I want it to be moving in, red arrow is the direction it is moving in.

[GIF of issue](https://imgur.com/a/4hzKVQS)

This is my current player movement script (forgive me im new to all this):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool withWind; //temporary var to simulate the player is with the wind
    private float speed;
    [SerializeField] float turnSpeed;
    private float portstarboardInput;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    public Vector3 playerPos;
    public Quaternion playerRot;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerHealth = GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        withWind = true;
        playerRb.useGravity = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        portstarboardInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //transform.Rotate(playerPos, turnSpeed * portstarboardInput);
        //transform.RotateAround(transform.position,transform.up,Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
        transform.Rotate(0,transform.position.y * portstarboardInput,0);
        playerRot = transform.rotation;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && !playerHealth.isDead) // temporary forward movement
        {
            playerRb.AddForce(playerRot * transform.forward * CalculateSpeed(),ForceMode.Force);
            playerPos = transform.position;
            Debug.Log("Adding Force: " + speed);
        }
    }

    float CalculateSpeed()
    {
        if (withWind)
        {
            speed = Random.Range(100f,150f);
        }
        if (!withWind)
        {
            speed = 2.5f;
        }
        return speed;
    }
}
```

I've tried setting the AddForce to the transform.forward position (rather than Vector3.forward) and using AddRelativeForce. However I cant seem to get around this ice rink behaviour.

Comment: it seems you have a low friction and need to remember that boats dont turn that quick, so need to lerp your turnings..

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in they way you're detecting whether or not you're still pressing W.

```
Input.GetKeyDown()
```

gets called only once, the moment you press the key and only for the frame in which the input registered.

What you're looking for is

```
Input.GetKey()
```

which will register every single frame for the entire time you're pressing W.

This is your code modified

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool withWind; //temporary var to simulate the player is with the wind
    private float speed;
    [SerializeField] float turnSpeed;
    private float portstarboardInput;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    public Vector3 playerPos;
    public Quaternion playerRot;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerHealth = GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        withWind = true;
        playerRb.useGravity = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        portstarboardInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //transform.Rotate(playerPos, turnSpeed * portstarboardInput);
        //transform.RotateAround(transform.position,transform.up,Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
        transform.Rotate(0,transform.position.y * portstarboardInput,0);
        playerRot = transform.rotation;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !playerHealth.isDead) // temporary forward movement
        {
            playerRb.AddForce(playerRot * transform.forward * CalculateSpeed(),ForceMode.Force);
            playerPos = transform.position;
            Debug.Log("Adding Force: " + speed);
        }
    }

    float CalculateSpeed()
    {
        if (withWind)
        {
            speed = Random.Range(100f,150f);
        }
        if (!withWind)
        {
            speed = 2.5f;
        }
        return speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I tried it with GetKey instead but it still seems to act the same way (although it moves more consistently now so thats one issue solved), However it still seems to act like its on an ice rink. Ideally it would head in the direction the bow is facing and be able to perform curved turns. [Ice rink ship GIF 2](https://imgur.com/a/DynqSay)

Comment: I think the entire logic here might be flawed, as a ship is moving you want to be adding force it constantly each and every frame, gradually decreasing it over time, or increasing it while holding w. You should also limit the rotation of the ship based on the amount of force you're applying to the ship otherwise you'll get the "drifting" effect you see there.